# Pycuda performance benchmark: ElementwiseKernel vs cumath?

Tags: python, performance, pycuda

I wanted to check the difference in speed between `cumath` and `ElementwiseKernel`, since [this example](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/SimpleSpeedTest) shows that `Elementwise` can perform faster than `cumath`. I am testing a different operation, where I would guess that `Elementwise` would be the faster method.

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
from pycuda import gpuarray
from pycuda import cumath
from pycuda.elementwise import ElementwiseKernel
import numpy as np

start = drv.Event()
end = drv.Event()

N = 10**6

a = 2*np.ones(N,dtype=np.float64)

start.record()
np.exp(a)
end.record()
end.synchronize()
secs = start.time_till(end)*1e-3
print "Numpy",secs

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)
b_gpu = gpuarray.zeros_like(a_gpu)

kernel = ElementwiseKernel(
   "double *a,double *b",
   "b[i] = exp(a[i]);",
    "kernel")

start.record() # start timing
kernel(a_gpu,b_gpu)
end.record() # end timing
end.synchronize()
secs = start.time_till(end)*1e-3
print "Kernel",secs

start.record()
cumath.exp(a_gpu)
end.record()
end.synchronize()
secs = start.time_till(end)*1e-3
print "Cumath", secs
```

The first time I run it I get:

```
Numpy    0.022
Kernel   0.143
Cumath   0.147
```

The second run in the same Python interpreter:

```
Numpy    0.021
Kernel   0.138
Cumath   0.002
```

I understand that `ElementwiseKernel` and `cumath` are both slow on the first run, but I don't understand why `ElementwiseKernel` doesn't get any faster on the second run.

Comment: With CUDA 8.0 and pycuda 2016.1 I get the following timings `Numpy 0.017, Kernel 0.091, Cumath 0.093`. Bumping `N=10**8` this becomes `Numpy 1.50, Kernel 0.148, Cumath 0.163`.  I don't think this is an issue any more.